# How do I ensure that Scanner hasNextInt() asks for new input?

Tags: java, input, token, java.util.scanner

New programmer here. This is probably a really basic question, but it's stumping me nevertheless.

What I'm trying to do is write a method that supplies only one integer input so I can use that input in my main program without having to mess around with non-integer inputs. However, even writing the method to do that in its own method seems to be problematic.

```
public static int goodInput () {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); //construct scanner
    boolean test = input.hasNextInt(); //set a sentinel value
    while (test == false) { //enter a loop until I actually get an integer
        System.out.println("Integers only please"); //tell user to give me an integer
        test = input.hasNextInt(); //get new input, see if it's an integer
    }
    int finalInput = input.nextInt(); //once i have an integer, set it to a variable
    input.close(); //closing scanner
    return finalInput; //return my integer so I don't have to mess around with hasNextInt over there
}
```

This seems to be broken in multiple levels, but I'm not really sure why.

If I enter an integer value like 0 or 1 when I'm first asked for input, it should skip the loop entirely. But, instead, it enters the loop, and prints "Integers only please". Even worse, it doesn't actually ask for input while I'm in there, and just prints that line repeatedly.

I understand the latter problem is probably due to token issues, but I'm not necessarily sure how to solve them; closing and then reopening the scanner gets Eclipse to bug me over "duplicate objects", simply assigning the old input to a garbage String variable that is never used tells me that "No line was found" at runtime, and I'm not experienced enough to think of other ways to get new input.

Even once that's solved, I need to find some way to avoid entering the loop in the case of having an integer. I don't really understand why integer inputs inter the loop to begin with, so I'm not sure how this would be possible.

Please help? Sorry if this is an old question; tried looking at past questions but none of them seem to have the same problem that I have.

Comment: `input.nextInt();` will ask for a new input. `input.hasNextInt();` will check for next input available or not and will return true or false acordingly!

Comment: @shekharsuman: So is there any way to get input, not make any assumptions as to what type the input could be, check if the input is an int, and if not repeat? If I was to just have input.nextInt() in my actual loop and non-int input was made the code would just break, I believe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close: this works fine for me:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //construct scanner
while(!input.hasNextInt()) {
    input.next(); // next input is not an int, so consume it and move on
}
int finalInput = input.nextInt();
input.close(); //closing scanner
System.out.println("finalInput: " + finalInput);
```

By calling `input.next()` in your while loop, you consume the non-integer content and try again, and again, until the next input is an int.

Comment: +1,good! I was going to add this approach but,luckily stopped seeing your answer...

Comment: This also creates problems for me for some reason! When I rewrote my code (to have input.next() rather than modify my boolean), executing it still enters the loop when it should not and creates several exceptions: java.util.NoSuchElementException, java.util.Scanner.throwFor, and java.util.Scanner.next.

Comment: With this code, the console waits for input. If I type a non-integer value and hit enter, it simply starts a new line and waits for more input. As soon as I type an integer value and hit enter the program outputs the integer value and execution stops. What do you see when you run this code by itself (without including it in your larger code project)?

Comment: Using your own code works exactly as it should, but changing my lines 3-7 with yours 2-4 (but including the print from mine) does not.

Comment: That suggests you have problems elsewhere in your code project. (Some of your exceptions suggested problems in a different method.) You might need to isolate the source of those problems and ask a new question if you can't work out the cause.

Comment: Yeah, you're right; calling the new method from main rather than just calling it from another, more sketchy method works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to help. If you think this answer solves your problem, click the tick below the voting buttons for this answer to accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
//while (test == false) {                         // Line #1
while (!test) { /* Better notation */             // Line #2
    System.out.println("Integers only please");   // Line #3
    test = input.hasNextInt();                    // Line #4
}                                                 // Line #5
```

The problem is that in line #4 above, `input.hasNextInt()` only tests if an integer is inputted, and does not ask for a new integer. If the user inputs something *other* than an integer, `hasNextInt()` returns `false` and you cannot ask for `nextInt()`, because then an `InputMismatchException` is thrown, since the `Scanner` is still expecting an integer.

You must use `next()` instead of `nextInt()`:

```
while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
    input.next();
    // That will 'consume' the result, but doesn't use it.
}
int result = input.nextInt();
input.close();
return result;
```